# JQuery, Datepicker...OnSelect wont work in IE

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

Ok...really bugging me.  Was working on all platforms, but for some reason, is not now.  Go figure, IE is causing problems with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ecalendar").datepicker({ 
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        alert("Finally!"); 
      }, 
      beforeShowDay: setScheduledDays
    }); 
});
```

Works great in every browser except IE.  I know this has been asked a billion times, but none of the other answers garnered any results.

Comment: wait...tested it in 8.0.6 and works fine...in 8.0.76 breaks.

Comment: i will try to conjure up a mockup...this is on an intranet site

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting your select list like so:

```
$("#ecalendar select").datepicker({
```